# PDFCreator remove blank pages

Tags: pdf, excel, vba

I use the PDFCreator in my Excel and to generate pdf files 
The Printarea specified contains data dynamically populated and due to this there are blank pages that get added to the pdf document .

How do i remove these blank pages while generating the pdf document ?

Comment: `1` Which Excel version are you using? If Excel 2007 or greater then Excel already has a built it facility to create the pdf `2` Why not recalculate the printarea before printing?

Comment: Yep, re calculated the print area and got it to working . Thanks. 
Also, You say that Excel 2007 or Greater has built in facility ? Can i programatically create PDF's from say the VB code ?Without installing a third part like the "PDFCreator" ?

Comment: Yes you can... See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee834871%28v=office.11%29.aspx